# How to attach accessiblityLabel to CheckBox from react-native-elements

Tags: react-native, accessibility, react-native-elements

I'm trying to prepare my React native code for testing with `Appium 2`.
We use `CheckBox` from [`react-native-elements`](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/components/checkbox).

I tried to add `accessibilityLabel` like this

```
import {CheckBox} from 'react-native-elements'

<Checkbox
    accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
    checkedIcon={<CheckboxCheckedIcon />}
    uncheckedIcon={<CheckboxUncheckedIcon />}
    onPress={() => onChange?.(!checked)}
    checked={checked}
    containerStyle={{height: SIZE, width: SIZE, margin: 0, padding: 2,...customContainerStyle}}
  />
```

But when I open it with [Appium inspector](https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector) the accessibility id is not there. So I think it is not propagated correctly.

- is it even possible?
- how do you achieve accessibility/testability of such checkbox?

thanks for any tips&tricks

Answer (score 0):

Well... what worked, in the end, was to find the label and then send the `tap` action directly.

```
const checkBox = await driver.$('~my_checkbox_label')
await driver.touchAction({
        action: 'tap',
        element: checkBox
    });
```